# Pool Prices Not Updating in Forked Hardhat Mainnet

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, hardhat

Why do pool prices remain static in my forked Hardhat mainnet environment during swaps? What steps can I take to troubleshoot and ensure that pool prices accurately reflect the expected changes in this forked environment?